# Integral convergence with two sequences of functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, limits-and-convergence

I came across this theorem just stated but has not proved and marked by 'it is easy to see'.

> **Theorem** If $u_m$ and $v_m$ converges to $u$ and $v$ in $L^2([0,T];H^1(\Omega))$ weakly and $L^2([0,T];L^2(\Omega))$ strongly, then for $w\in C(\overline{[0,T]\times \Omega})$,
> $$\int_{0}^{T}\int_\Omega v_mwu_mdxdt\xrightarrow[m\rightarrow \infty]{} 
>  \int_{0}^{T}\int_\Omega vwudxdt$$
> where $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f\in L^2([0,T];L^2(\Omega))$ means that  $$\int_{0}^T\|f(t)\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}dt<\infty$$
> and
> $$\int_{0}^T\|f(t)\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}dt=\int_{0}^{T} \int_\Omega |f(t,x)|^2dxdt.$$ And we use analogous definition for $L^2([0,T];H^1(\Omega))$.

---

The books says it is easy to see but I cannot come up with any useful tool to prove this. I guess the peculiar definition of $L^2([0,T],L^2(\Omega))$ would not be big matter. Does anybody know any idea on it?

---

I thought it is better to add the book where I saw this theorem. The question I asked is refined version of this following theorem.

[image]

The title of this book is 'Navier-Stokes Equations Theory and Numerical Analysis' written by Roger Temam. And it is page 289.